# Which one is preferable over another associative array with boolean value or with null value?

Tags: php

I need to look up whether key exists in the associative array or not, I don't care about its value (The reason I use associative array is it is implemented by using hash tables which is O(1)).
So which one is efficient to use `["tural" => null, "elvin" => null]` or `["tural" => true, "elvin" => true]` , namely should I store `boolean` or `null`?

Comment: Wouldn't storing `null` be better in terms of memory consumption

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya this is exactly what I ask about. But with explanation.

Comment: Why the value matters if you are checking whether a key exists?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen why not use better one which is cheaper also in terms of memory?

Comment: You are forgetting the context of your application. Yes, in a vacuum "null" is better in terms of memory. Seek time is still the same, right? There are reasons why you could use boolean instead of null. For example if you want to avoid null values or semantically it might make more sense to make it a boolean. It is a tradeoff, would you agree? You should choose the one that makes more sense for your application.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen The only thing I care is whether it exists in the list or not. Its value doesn't matter. The context is this.